# ios13: I want to get the selected device mode (dark mode / light mode ) inside my application

Tags: swift, ios13, ios-darkmode

Currently i have enabled dark mode in my iphone.
but UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle always returns current mode as "Unspecified".

I want to get the device/system/os mode that is currently selected.

````
if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
        print("Yes dark mode")
      } else {
        print("Not dark mode")
      }```
````

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: Maybe `UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle` gives the current device setting.

Comment: @rmaddy It still gives me the same results. Keerthi, have you ever found the solution?